# General solution of a second order, non-homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How might I go about computing the general solution (i.e. with an arbitrary initial condition) of
$$tu''−(t+1)u'+u=t^2$$
where $u'= \frac{du}{dt}$ and $u''= \frac{d^2u}{dt^2}$
I am a bit confused. Can anyone give me the exact solution?

Comment: Can you find one nontrivial homogeneous solution? Once you do you can apply reduction of order followed by variation of parameters to turn the crank.

Comment: Assume ODE implies t const. Then, suggest attempt $u_h=\alpha e^{\beta x}$ for the homogeneous equation. The inhomogeneous one with $u=u_h\cdot \tilde{u}$

Comment: @SamGinrich What? $t$ is the independent variable here.

Comment: @Ian independent from ...? I expect a proper definition of functional and variables.

Comment: @SamGinrich Independent as in the "time" variable. Assuming it is $x$ when there's no $x$ anywhere in the problem is just being obtuse for no reason. This isn't a good question in general but that isn't why.

Comment: yes, time derivations usually go with dot, one can guess ...

Comment: @SamGinrich In the physics literature sure, in the math literature and especially the pedagogical math literature that is quite rare.

Comment: The equation has a nicely visible  structure, $t(u'-u)'-(u'-u)=t^2$ so that one can split this into two sequentially dependent first-order equations $tv'-v=t^2$ and $u'-u=v$. Both are now easily solvable via integrating factors.